# Illustrator power shortcut

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transform, shortcuts

EDIT: Is there a direct shortcut to access the `Width` field on the **Transform Panel** in Illustrator?

---

Original text:

transform panel ( panel select box width ) shortcut key required.
shift +f8 normal. (But not  select width box)
Direct width selected shortcut.?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is a direct method of accessing an objects width via any shortcut.

While <kbd>F8</kbd> is the default shortcut to *show* the Transform Panel, there are no shortcuts to access the fields or options within the panel itself.